# javascript: execute code before click event is dispatched

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm using jQuery Mobile + backbone.js to build a one-page app.

Backbone.js is used to handle routing and templates (actually underscore.js handles that), jQuery mobile is usded to provide the style, and give support for some mobile events (pageshow, pagebeforeshow, etc)

The application works completely offline and is intended to be used in tablets mobile devices. (Android 2.3+)

When i click on an element, i use backbone.js router to get the resources involved (e.g. /product/:id means I must show data about product with specified id) 
I get the data from localStorage (was previously saved), filter the data, send it to a template to generate the html, and modify the DOM to update the view.

When the app runs in the mobile device there is a small delay between clicking the element and the page actually reflecting the new state.
That's not a terrible issue, but i need to provide some feedback to the user so I'm trying to show the "page loading" indicator whenever the user clicks on some elements, before changing the view state. That's when I hit a wall...

**The problem**
If I register an event handler for the 'click' elements involved, the page loading never shows, as after finishing the event handler code, the default action for the click handler takes place and the view is not redraw.
Using setTimeout doesn't help neither, as in that case the calculations start and the indicator is shown after they finish, i.e. when the page is actually in the new state, so the indicator either doesn't even show, or just show briefly before being dismissed.

I've tried almost any solution I could though of:

- show the indicator in the click/mousedown/tapdown events -> Tried this, but
  for some reason the click event is sometimes NOT triggered

Routing works ok, but, the moment I add a code like this:

```
 $(document).bind('click', function(element) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
  });
```

Then it starts to drop click events: the loading indicator is shown, but the routing does even takes place.
If I do not use that code, all works ok.

- Using a 'fastclick' code
  (https://github.com/cargomedia/jquery.touchToClick) to intercept the
  click event and show the indicator and then  trigger the click event
  in the element manually: again, sometimes the manually triggered
  click event just doesn't shows up :(

Any ideas? I must be missing something :(

Comment: What are those calculations that cause the delay, are they asynchronous? And why did adding an extra click handler disable the view event?

Comment: I'm just getting data from localStorage and ordering it before sending it to a template, and once generated, change the DOM to show the new state. If there is many data it can take a second or two. 
The app is meant to run offline, forgot to mention

Comment: "And why did adding an extra click handler disable the view event?"

I don't understand that question.

Comment: You said that you registered an event handler, but then the view is never shown. Or is your problem similar to [show message during synchronous calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11568028/1048572) (no js function should need seconds to execute)?

Comment: The view is not show because the click event is not propagated, son the routing code (which changes the view) doesn't get executed.
(i didn't stop propagation nor default event in the handler)

Comment: I'm actually showing the indicator before executing the code to change the view, but the brownser doesn't show it.

And is not a single function taking seconds, but the whole process (click event handler to show indicator -> anchor click default event tells the browser to change url -> backbone.js router code kicks in -> get data for the resource from localStorage -> filter and order the data -> generate html from template -> update DOM)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, this made the question more clear. And yes, by "function" I meant that one huge synchronous process